# Cut when csv file has commas in cell linux

Tags: mysql, linux, csv

I have IMDB data in csv format.  Here is a snapshot.

```
[root@jamatney IMDB]# head IMDBMovie.txt
id,name,year,rank
0,#28 (2002),2002,
1,#7 Train: An Immigrant Journey, The (2000),2000,
2,$ (1971),1971,6.4000000000000004
3,$1000 Reward (1913),1913,
4,$1000 Reward (1915),1915,
5,$1000 Reward (1923),1923,
6,$1,000,000 Duck (1971),1971,5
7,$1,000,000 Reward, The (1920),1920,
8,$10,000 Under a Pillow (1921),1921,
```

I'd like to import this data into a MySQL database.  However there are commas present in the name cells.  This prevents me from loading the data into the database correctly, as my loading query is,

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'IMDB/IMDBMovie.txt' INTO TABLE Movie FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I've thought about using some combination of `rev` and `cut` to isolate the offending column, then find/replace the commas, but can't seem to get it to work.  Was wondering if this is the right approach, or if there's a better way.

Comment: Something about that `[root@...` prompt makes me shudder...

Comment: it's a digitalocean droplet

Comment: ... it must be all that water... Seriously now, for most DB management tasks such as loading data there is no need to use the system `root` account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the first field and last two fields are unambiguous, so all you have to do is write a script to pull those out, and surround what remains in quotes. My bash-fu isn't quite good enough to get it done with `rev` and `cut`, but I was able to write a Python script to get it done. You can add an `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY` clause to your `LOAD DATA` query.

```
    f = open("IMDBMovie.txt")                                                
    print(next(f)) # header                                                  
    for line in f:                                                           
        fields = line.strip().split(",")                                     

        # Get unambiguous fields.                                            
        id = fields.pop(0)                                                   
        rank = fields.pop(-1)                                                
        year = fields.pop(-1)                                                

        # Surround name with quotes.                                         
        name = '"{}"'.format(",".join(fields))                                                                                            
        print("{},{},{},{}".format(id, name, year, rank))
```

On your test data, the output was

```
        id,name,year,rank
        0,"#28 (2002)",2002,
        1,"#7 Train: An Immigrant Journey, The (2000)",2000,
        2,"$ (1971)",1971,6.4000000000000004
        3,"$1000 Reward (1913)",1913,
        4,"$1000 Reward (1915)",1915,
        5,"$1000 Reward (1923)",1923,
        6,"$1,000,000 Duck (1971)",1971,5
        7,"$1,000,000 Reward, The (1920)",1920,
        8,"$10,000 Under a Pillow (1921)",1921,
```

Comment: You're welcome! I just edited to remind that you have to put something like ``FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Good luck.  Your input file is in a lousy format.  It is not really CSV.  Here are two options:

(1) Open the file in Excel (or your favorite spreadsheet) and save it out with tab delimiters instead.  Keep your fingers crossed that none of the fields have a tab.  Or use another delimiter such as a pipe character.

(2) Load each row into a table with only one column, a big character string column.  Then, parse the rows into their constituent fields (`substring_index()` can be very useful).